# How can I tell CDK to bundle Lambda layer assets for x86_64 on an M1 Mac?

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm struggling with our CDK snapshots tests computing different asset hash values locally on my M1 MacBook and remotely with GitHub actions.
I stored the `cdk.out` directory created on GitHub as an action artifact and compared the contents of `cdk.out` to identify the difference.
It boils down to the way we bundle our asset for the Lambda layer in `generator.ts`:

```js
const lambdaLayer = new lambda.LayerVersion(this, 'layer', {
  code: Code.fromAsset(pathToLayerSource, {
    bundling: {
      image: cdk.DockerImage.fromBuild(pathToLayerSource, { file: 'Dockerfile' }),
      command: ['bash', '-c', 'rsync -a --exclude Pipfile /tmp/build/ /asset-output'],
      // platform: 'linux/amd64', // this didn't help, see below
    },
  }),
  description: `Layer for ${Generator.SERVICE_NAME} stack`,
  layerVersionName: commons.getIdentifierForStage(Generator.SERVICE_NAME),
});
```

Here is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.10:latest

ARG TMP_BUILD=/tmp/build

RUN yum makecache fast; yum clean all && yum -y update && yum -y upgrade; yum clean all && \
    yum install -y yum-plugin-ovl; yum clean all && yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"; yum clean all

RUN yum -y install postgresql-devel && pip install pipenv

WORKDIR ${TMP_BUILD}
COPY Pipfile .
COPY Pipfile.lock .

RUN pipenv requirements > requirements.txt && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt -t python --no-cache-dir

WORKDIR /var/task
```

When I build the asset locally, *charset_normalizer* is installed to the `python` directory of the layer with these files:

- md.cpython-310-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
- md__mypyc.cpython-310-aarch64-linux-gnu.so

However, the `cdk.out` of the GitHub action contains these files for the asset instead:

- md.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
- md__mypyc.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

I want to instruct CDK to bundle for `linux/amd64` and specified the `platform` in the `BundlingOptions` but that didn't change that `aarch64` CPython libraries are installed for *charset_normalizer*.
Does anyone know how I can achieve my goal to compute the same asset hash values locally by instructing CDK to bundle for the x64_86 architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke it with

`DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64 cdk deploy`

should work, given that the image building does work under emulation. Not all images run nicely with rosetta/qemu, but enabling rosetta emulation in docker desktop probably helps.

There is another problem with docker (older versions, I think it fixed in the latest version), that if you once pulled an image for the wrong arch, it wont pull a new one when switching arch. Hence, you might need to purge the image before trying to switch to linux/amd64. But, in the later Docker Desktop this seems to have been fixed (at least 4.26.0)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This does bundle the asset with the proper `*.so`-files but the hash value still differs. I reckon this will be a different issue.

Comment: @oschlueter Yeah, I've seen that as well. I have been fiddling with .dockerignore etc to make the selection for the hash to be equivalent, but I think my conclusion was that modified times for the files will always differ locally versus in CI so the hash would never match. But can't say for sure.